# Sampling from a recursively defined distribution

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

I'd like to know if there are techniques for sampling from a recursively defined probability distribution, assuming that solving the recursion for a formula for the distribution is too difficult.

As an example of what I have in mind by a recursively defined distribution take $p(t) = p(t-1)^2 + p(t-2)^3$, $t \in \mathbb{N}$, and choose the initial values that make it a probability distribution.

Comment: For the example you have, this sequence would converge to zero fairly quickly. Why not store the first probabilities until reaching the underflow bound, numerical precision-wise, and then do accept reject with some other distribution (say Negative binomial) whose parameters you would have optimized for the accept-reject algorithm to have good properties?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is solve your recursion and then sample using the resulting probabilities.

So for example in R you might assume $p(0)=0$ and use the following

```
max_n         <- 20            # number of probabilities to calculate
p             <- rep(0, max_n) 
rec_p         <- function(x1, steps=20){
                   p[1]   <- x1 
                   p[2]   <- p[1]^2 
                   for (i in 3:steps){ p[i] <- p[i-1]^2 + p[i-2]^3 }
                   p
                   }   
err_rec_p     <- function(x){ abs(sum(rec_p(x, max_n)) - 1) }
best_p1       <- optimize( f=err_rec_p, interval=c(0,1), tol = 1e-9 )$minimum
probabilities <- rec_p(best_p1, max_n) / sum(rec_p(best_p1, max_n))
```

to get the probabilities

```
 [1]  5.005662e-01  2.505666e-01  1.882088e-01  5.115401e-02  9.283564e-03
 [6]  2.200409e-04  8.485179e-07  1.137392e-11  6.110475e-19  1.471774e-33
[11]  2.281524e-55  3.188038e-99 1.187613e-164 3.240190e-296  0.000000e+00
[16]  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
```

and then sample using these probabilities

```
samplesize <- 75
sample(1:max_n, samplesize, replace=TRUE, prob=probabilities )
```

which might for example give the following values

```
 [1] 1 1 2 3 1 3 4 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 2 5 1 3 3 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 1 2 1 1 3 2 3 1
[39] 2 1 3 2 3 2 2 3 1 1 2 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 1 3 1 3 1 3 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the distribution you gave will go to zero very rapidly, an efficient sampling method might simply be the obvious one given as follows (assuming your initial probabilities $p(1)$ and $p(2)$ are known):

1. Set $k=1$.
2. Sample $u$ uniformly from $[0,1]$.
3. If $u < p(k)$, choose $t_k$ and exit.
4. Otherwise, set:

   $u \leftarrow u - p(k)$

   $p(k+2) = p(k+1)^2 + p(k)^3$

   $k \leftarrow k+1$

   And repeat from step 3.

I hope it's clear what is being done here. We're simply using the CDF method and counting on the fact that on average $k$ will be incremented very few times before accepting an answer.